Odd errors when trying to verify a requests.post call using pytest-mockito
I'm trying out the pytest-mockito library for some unit testing (I'm primarily a kotlin/java engineer and I think the mockito syntax reads a bit nicer). Most of it makes sense, but I'm running into a weird error when trying to verify a post request.
class TestSuite:
    def test_verify_we_sent_data_somewhere(self):
        api_url = "http://www.somebooksearch.biz/search"
        payload = {"title": "An updated title", "isbn": 12345}

        update_book(payload)

        verify(requests).post(api_url, data=None, json=payload)

# Implementation:

def update_book(payload):
    requests.post("http://www.somebooksearch.biz/search", json=payload)

When I fire my test case I get the error:
verify(requests).post(api_url, json=payload, **kwargs) E       mockito.mockito.ArgumentError: obj '<module 'requests' from '/Users/cschmitz/Engineering/projects/classroom-book-tracker/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>' is not registered

example_test.py:93: ArgumentError

It's weird though because I have a different test case where I'm mocking a get request and it passes just fine:
    def test_mock_an_external_library_but_without_comments(self):
        api_url = "http://www.somebooksearch.biz/search"

        mock_response = mock({
            "json": lambda: {"books": [{"title": "Some book title", "isbn": "123456"}]}
        })

        when(requests).get(api_url).thenReturn(mock_response)

        actual = get_book_list()

        assert actual == [{"title": "Some book title", "isbn": "123456"}]

# Implementation
def get_book_list():
    response = requests.get("http://www.somebooksearch.biz/search")
    data = response.json()
    return data["books"]

I see it's saying there's an argument error, but I'm not sure exactly what it means. I know the library's walkthrough says that the mock arguments are really picky, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing or have wrong. Any help is appreciated!
